# Inserindo data no padrão americano

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um função para importar dados de um documento txt, o layout que uso para importar esses dados é delimitado por ponto e vírgula, tenho as seguintes colunas (numero,data_inclusao,remetente,moeda,valor,situacao,status). O problema está na hora de inserir a data, pois no txt uso o padrão brasileiro dd/mm/aaaa e no mysql ele não aceita esse padrão, como faço pra converter essa data para o padrão americano antes de rodar o insert?

meu código:

```
 <?php

    function Inserir($itens, Pdo $pdo){
        $sts = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO orpags(numero,data_inclusao,remetente,moeda,valor,situacao,status) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,'1');");
        $sts->bindValue(1, $itens[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sts->bindValue(2, $itens[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sts->bindValue(3, $itens[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sts->bindValue(4, $itens[3], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sts->bindValue(5, $itens[4], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sts->bindValue(6, $itens[5], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sts->execute();
        $sts->closeCursor();
        $sts = NULL;

     /* por ponto e virgula*/
            }
    if (!empty($_FILES['arquivo']))
    {
        $Pdo     = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=smoke", "root", "");
        $file    = fopen($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], 'r');
        while (!feof($file)){
            $linha = fgets($file);          
            $itens = explode(';', $linha);          
            Inserir($itens, $Pdo);
        }
    }


?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Arquivo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="arquivo" id="arquivo">
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removi `$itens[1]` e inseri `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($itens[1]))` que está fazendo a conversão para o padrão internacional.

```
<?php

function Inserir($itens, Pdo $pdo){
    $sts = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO orpags(numero,data_inclusao,remetente,moeda,valor,situacao,status) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,'1');");
    $sts->bindValue(1, $itens[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sts->bindValue(2,date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($itens[1])), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sts->bindValue(3, $itens[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sts->bindValue(4, $itens[3], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sts->bindValue(5, $itens[4], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sts->bindValue(6, $itens[5], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sts->execute();
    $sts->closeCursor();
    $sts = NULL;

 /* por ponto e virgula*/
        }
if (!empty($_FILES['arquivo']))
{
    $Pdo     = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=smoke", "root", "");
    $file    = fopen($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], 'r');
    while (!feof($file)){
        $linha = fgets($file);          
        $itens = explode(';', $linha);          
        Inserir($itens, $Pdo);
    }
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Arquivo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="arquivo" id="arquivo">
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A função `strtotime` não aceita o padrão brasileiro como parâmetro ([veja este exemplo](https://3v4l.org/kn5V9)). [Lista de padrões aceitos](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função `date()`:

date("YYYY/MM/dd", strtotime("26/01/2018"));

Referência: [Documentação PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php).

Comment: O formato de data DD/MM/YY (26/01/2018) não é reconhecido pela função `strtotime` ([formatos aceitos](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)) e o formato de saída não é o que é aceito pelo mysql (YY-MM-DD). Veja no exemplo: https://3v4l.org/tH9op